# Node.js bcrypt compare problem only return false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

I want to do my login API with Node.js and MongoDB and when I compare my pass from input to the one that's in the db I always get false I read other post on StackOverFlow but didn't helped me.

I think I also found the problem: When I use hash on my password input to check it manually with the one from db at every request is onatherone.

So maybe that's the problem but I don't know how to solve. I read a lot about this but still cant solve here is my code:

```
const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (res) => {console.log(res)}) //false
```

my login api

```
router.post('/login', body('email').isEmail(), body('password').exists(), async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body

    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ "err": "invalid credentials" })
    }

    // const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(function (res) { console.log(res) })

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    console.log(match)

})
```

and here is the register api

```
router.post("/register", body("email").isEmail(), body("password").isLength({ min: 5 }), body("username").isLength({ min: 1 }), async (req, res) => {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const saltRounds = 10;

    try {
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
        }
        //check if the user exist
        const duplicated = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (duplicated) { return res.status(401).json({ "err": "Email is taken" }) }
        const user = new User({ username, email, password })

        //crypt pass
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(process.env.secret, saltRounds);

        //generate token with jwt
        const payload = {
            id: user.id
        }

        jwt.sign({
            payload,
        }, process.env.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '999h' }, (err, token) => { console.log(token) });
        //save the user
        await user.save()
        res.status(200).send("User Stored")

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.body)
    }

})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226849/discussion-on-question-by-grind-node-js-bcrypt-compare-problem-only-return-false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you using `bcrypt.hash` in the wrong way.
It seems like you provide this method kind of key, which you shall not provide.
This method accepts the value to hash, and `saltRounds`.

So you basically need to change your Registration API code to:

```
router.post("/register", body("email").isEmail(), body("password").isLength({ min: 5 }), body("username").isLength({ min: 1 }), async (req, res) => {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const saltRounds = 10;

    try {
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
        }
        //check if the user exist
        const duplicated = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (duplicated) { return res.status(401).json({ "err": "Email is taken" }) }
        const user = new User({ username, email, password })

        //crypt pass
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);

        //generate token with jwt
        const payload = {
            id: user.id
        }

        jwt.sign({
            payload,
        }, process.env.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '999h' }, (err, token) => { console.log(token) });
        //save the user
        await user.save()
        res.status(200).send("User Stored")

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.body)
    }
}
```

And more specific, you store the password with:

```
user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `Promise` for this

```js
const match = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(error, res){
    if (error) { reject(error); }
    resolve(res);
  })
})
```

Comment: i dont think the problem is how i wrote this the problem is the pass is not the same as the db